# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'current' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, django-views

I'm using django to aggregate averages, sums, etc, of a queryset and have the code below. What I expect is that the case matches the period and then the sum and average is computed further down the code but I get the error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'current' referenced before assignment`

```
def metrics(request):
    email = request.data.get("email")
    period = request.data.get("period") # [0,1,2,3 : day, week, month, year]

    today = date.today()
    weekday = date.isoweekday(today)
    month = today.month
    year = today.year
    current_week = date.isocalendar(today).week

    store = Store.objects.get(account__email=email)
    sales = Order.objects.filter(store=store)

    match period:
        case 0:
            # 'Today'
            current = sales.filter(created__week_day=weekday)
            past = sales.filter(created__week_day=weekday - 1)
        case 1:
            # 'This week'
            current = sales.filter(created__week=current_week) 
            past = sales.filter(created__week=current_week - 1)
        case 2:
            # 'This month'
            current = sales.filter(created__month=month)
            past = sales.filter(created__month=month - 1)
        case 3:
            # 'This year'
            current = sales.filter(created__year=year)
            past = sales.filter(created__year=year - 1)

    current_total = current.aggregate(Sum('products_total'))['products_total__sum']
    past_total = past.aggregate(Sum('products_total'))['products_total__sum']

    current_average = current.aggregate(Avg('products_total'))['products_total__avg']
    past_average = past.aggregate(Avg('products_total'))['products_total__avg']

    current_count = current.count()
    past_count = past.count()
```

Printing the values, I get:

```
# today:  2023-05-20
# weekday:  6
# month:  5
# year: 2023
# current week:  20
```

products_total is a field in my model but I don't think is relevant to the question:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    products_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
    ...
```

I've tried using `if/elif` statements but get the same error.

I've also read through this similar question but can't see how it relates or how to edit my code accordingly: [UnboundLocalError trying to use a variable (supposed to be global) that is (re)assigned (even after first use)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-trying-to-use-a-variable-supposed-to-be-global-that-is-rea)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `period` variable does not match any of the values in your `match`. That way `current` will never get initialized and you end up with this error.

You can add `case _:` which will match the values not fitting into any of the other `case` in the `match`.

Comment: Thanks. I have a follow up question in the link below. Can you please help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76294456/django-template-response-contentnotrenderederror-the-response-content-must-be-r